# .dbml .cs File throws Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listview

I have a listview bound to a LinqDataSource

I have steped thorugh the code and it gets to this section of the .dbml file of the xx.designer.cs

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<qtxt_Competition> qtxt_Competitions     
{
 get{     
     return this.GetTable<qtxt_Competition>();    
 }     
}
```

and once it passes the return it throws this error

> at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableDataSourceView.OriginalValueMatches(Object
>   originalValue, Object value)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableDataSourceView.GetOriginalValues(IDictionary
>   keys)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableDataSourceView.BuildUpdateObjects(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues, IDictionary`2
>   validationErrors)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContextDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues)   at
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary
>   values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback
>   callback)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.HandleUpdate(ListViewItem item,
>   Int32 itemIndex, Boolean causesValidation)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean
>   causesValidation, String validationGroup)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e)   at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e)   at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) 
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) 
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Ok the strange thing is that for some records it will update fine but for other it keeps throwing this error

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of this ambiguios error :)

If you have a Datakey in a list view which conatins null values in the database this is the resulting error.